# New tag-based “Random Question” link like the “Random article” link on Wikipedia

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

Quite recently, I read that one good way to learn something new is to hit the “Random article” link in Wikipedia.

I thought that for people who want to learn something new in IT, a great addition would be a “Random Post” link on Stack Overflow.

- Since we want to learn in a said direction, this link should be tag-oriented (e.g. on the tag page).
- Since it’s about learning something, the filtering query should take into consideration only questions / answers with a high enough grade.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/random-question-button

Comment: Maybe there should be also a cross site duplicate search for Meta.SO and Meta.SE ;-) My bad, sorry.

Comment: @MauriceKlimek No need to apologize for not finding an 11yo duplicate from a different site! It happens lol

Comment: As an aside, this is one of the reasons I enjoy reviewing answers—and even in languages and frameworks I'm not normally interested or invested into. It gives me an excuse to learn random tidbits that I wouldn't otherwise have thought to seek out, and can help establish a broader awareness of what else is going on in the coding world.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing that appears to be available right now is a webapp that a user named [@Gelatin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16822/gelatin) put together some time ago, called "[DiceStack](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/)".

It's got [a page over on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/1643/dice-stack-find-a-random-question). It appears to still work fine, but reporting any bugs might be hit or miss– the StackApps page hasn't been active in 5+ years. According to that page, it's free to use, but not open source, so mileage may vary.

It allows filtering by site, minimum score (1/ 10/ 100), tags (up to 5), and answer status (no answers/ no accepted answer/ any).

---

There are no official SE solutions for this at the moment, but it did receive a favorable response as a feature-request when it was [posted to MSE in 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/random-question-button). Times have changed *just* a little since then though, so not certain how much traction it'd get today.